# Magento2 Getting following error when trying to create shipment from admin for config product

Tags: magento2

```
Undefined index: simple_sku in /vendor/magento/module-inventory-configurable-product/Plugin/Sales/GetSkuFromOrderItem.php on line 38
```

Following is the error I am getting when trying to create shipment for config product from admin

Comment: check please your products in that order exists or not, sometimes this issue occurs when the order has a item which is deleted.

Comment: order item is present I verified

Comment: place test order with simple  product and test this issue only exists with configs? and did you recently migrated to new version?

Comment: I haven't migrated. And it is working fine with simple product

Comment: version you are working on?

Comment: I am facing issue when overriding getOrderOptions() function vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/AbstractType.php

Comment: How can I do it using aftermethod

Comment: kinldy share your code for overiding

Answer (score 0):

**use this code to overide it** :

```
namespace Namespace\YourModule\Model\Product\Type;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType;

class ClassNamePlugin
{
    /**
     * @param AbstractType $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function aroundGetOrderOptions(AbstractType $subject, callable $proceed, $product): array
    {


         //use arround method to achieve it.
        // your code goes here



        return $proceed($product);
    }
}
```